# Excel- Matching dupe values and return the earlier date out of the dupes

Tags: excel

I have a table of orders from customers. A customer could have made more than one purchase so they will be in the table twice. I'm looking to find the 1st purchase date and amount of each customer in the table. I thought that it could be accomplished with nested IF's but I'm just not sure how it works since the data points are in other columns. Take a look at the screenshot. I want to be able to pull for '1st order amount' and '1st order date'.

Any help or direction is much appreciated. Thanks!

[Table example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6zeM.png)

Comment: Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in E2:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A2,A2)<=1,INDEX(B:B,MATCH(A2,A:A,0)),"")
```

Put this in F2:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A2,A2)<=1,INDEX(D:D,MATCH(A2,A:A,0)),"")
```

Then copy down:

One caveat:  The data must be sorted by Order Date.

[image]

Comment: Hey Scott, thanks so much! This worked great. I appreciate your help on this. I'll be googling every piece of your formula to fully understand what happened there.